# elasticsearch error:DataAccessResourceFailureException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE];

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:425)
... 108 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]

Comment: you've only posted an error here, nothing else, so it's going to be impossible to help you without more information on where you are getting this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. I had -Xmx2g set and my java springboot process died with a java heap error for me at 47% through my process. Then I changed to -Xmx8g and i no longer get a heap error at 47% thought my process. I now get the exact error you have.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is using the default timeout. Configure your RestClient as follows:

```
return 
  new RestHighLevelClient(
      RestClient.builder(
        HttpHost.create(__elasticEndpointUrl__))
          .setHttpClientConfigCallback( hacb -> hacb.addInterceptorLast(__interceptorHere__))
          .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(__timeOutHere__)
          .setSocketTimeout(__**putHighValueHere**__)));
```